# Adobe Flash text input

Tags: flash, text, adobe

How does one link input text of one frame, respective to another frame.

For example:

- If a user inputs `903` on main frame, when they select submit, I want to link him to 903 frame
- If user inputs `905`, go to 905...

**Is that possible, if so, how?**

Comment: Look up these keywords in your search engine : **AS3 user input textfield**. Put all your frames into one MovieClip's timeline (cut/paste if needed). Your MClip, Textfield for link inpts, and all your AS3 code should all be on frame 1 (just different layers). Use an `If` statement to check if they typed **903** then tell `MClip.gotoAndStop(093);`.

Comment: Well im little newbie in all this. Sorryfor bothering...but i have one frame for main page..this is for aplication for android. From that page i have to link those text inputs to another frames (pages). I have no idea where to put and how that Mclip. I have to put layers for each input? Or? Thank you

Comment: I have more then 100 inputs available with all data available for each one. So its easier for me to make one frame for each input and link it. As far as i understand. Right?

Comment: Can i do somwthing like this i just found. 
if(Login.text == "BANANA"){
gotoAndStop(2);
} So for each input link to its frame? Bit i dont know exactly how and where to put it...